# How to define the route to external link with query

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to make the route definition to external link **with query string** for **path** by using `beforeEnter()`as follows:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    beforeEnter() {location.href = '/path='+this.$router.query.path},
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home3
  },
```

But I've got an error as "Can't read properties of undefined (reading $route)".

[image]

How should I write the correct definition to external link with query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are 3 params](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) in `beforeEnter`

Your code should be like this:

```
beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
  location.href = '/path=' + to.query.path
  next()
}
```

Comment: It's working perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: I just edited, remember to call next() to resolve the route.